# CppCheck ignores the usage of variables in macro definitions, how to change that?

Tags: cppcheck

The output of running CppCheck on my code displays the following error:
`Variable 'strFullPath' is assigned a value that is never used. [unreadVariable]`

The method below is the one in discussion.

```cpp
void DebugLogging::GetDebugLogSettings(const std::string& sAppProfile)
{
    std::string strFullPath = ROOT_KEY_NAME + sAppProfile;
    
#ifdef _WIN32
    std::string strFullPathLocal = strFullPath + "Local";
#else
    std::string sAppProfileLocal = sAppProfile + "Local";
    std::ifstream settingsLocalfile(sAppProfileLocal.c_str());
#endif
}
```

CppCheck states that `strFullPath`'s value is never used. However, it is used inside a macro.

How to setup CppCheck so it becomes capable of finding the usage of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it inside the macro.

```cpp
void DebugLogging::GetDebugLogSettings(const std::string& sAppProfile)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    std::string strFullPath = ROOT_KEY_NAME + sAppProfile;
    std::string strFullPathLocal = strFullPath + "Local";
#else
    std::string sAppProfileLocal = sAppProfile + "Local";
    std::ifstream settingsLocalfile(sAppProfileLocal.c_str());
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a Cppcheck developer. The fix Damian-Teodor Beles suggested is nice.

I just wanted to add some philosophy. In my humble opinion that particular warning is unfortunate. I consider it a false positive, as a human I can see that the value is used.

This false positive can be fixed in Cppcheck. We have fixed some related false positives but obviously not this one. It might be fixed in Cppcheck in the future but I can't promise when that would happen.

In general I assume that moving the variable is a nice fix. But maybe sometimes you don't want to move the variable. Then you could inline suppress the warning for now. When we fix this in Cppcheck, you will get a warning that says that the inline suppression is never used.. and then you can remove the comment.

Comment: this false-positive impacts catch2 and doctest where template/macros are used unfortuntely. anything wraps in CHECK() or REQUIRE can produce 'unreadvariable'

Comment: In the example code OP showed.. the code will be more clean and separated properly if the variable is moved into the proper #ifdef code. If you have problems with CHECK() and REQUIRE then I guess you have some different problem.